# Evaluate code to some point

Tags: evaluation

How can I evaluate my code, up to some point? I don't want to evaluate all of my code always.

I have to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>Enter</kbd> for every line from the first cell up to the point I want to be, and it's not easy when you have a lot of code.

Comment: You can also select the lines and press shift-enter once...

Comment: Also, remember that your "lines" can be grouped in "cells", and you need to press shift-enter only once in order to  process the whole cell

Comment: @rm-rf: Thanks .It's so useful.

Comment: For evaluating through a number of cells consecutively, repeated shift-enter (on Windows) evaluates a cell and jumps to the next one. Really useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16697/131, especially @Rolf Mertig´s anser: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16760/131

Answer (score 2):

Apart from selecting cells and evaluating, you could try

1. Mathematica's built-in debugger (under the Evaluation menu)
2. The workbench has a debugger
3. [DebugTrace](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/debugtrace/debugtrace.html) (which is probably closest to what you want)