# Combine InputAlias with InputString to parse expressions from a string

Tags: front-end

My knowledge of low-level notebook programming is very limited so I would be very grateful for any input regarding the following issue:

I would like to define an input alias (via `InputAliases`) that evaluates

```
parse[InputString[]]
```

*in-place* (like selecting it and then performing *Menu* → *Evaluation* → *Evaluate in Place* or `Cmd` + `Return`). The function `parse` will translate my textual input into an expression (and insert it at the current cursor position).

Currently, I am using the following alias,

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
    InputAliases->{"parse"->RowBox[{"parse","[","InputString","[","]","]"}]}]
```

and the workflow looks like this

1. `ESC` `parse` `ESC` to produce `parse[InputString[]]`
2. Press `Ctrl` + `.` a few times to select `parse[InputString[]]`
3. Evaluate in place via `Cmd` + `Return`
4. Type something into the input field and press `Return`

Basically, I would like to get rid of steps 2 and 3. I would appreciate any other solution if the desired behavior cannot be achieved using `InputAliases`. I would also be more than happy if an `InputField` could be used instead of `InputString`.

Comment: I would suggest setting a hotkey, like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16760/4330). I don't think you can start any evaluation from entering an InputAlias, so there seems to be little else you can do.

Answer (score 3):

Success! Please evaluate the following code in a new notebook:

```
 Clear[eval];
 eval[cmd_] := Module[{nb},
    nb = InputNotebook[];
    NotebookWrite[nb, cmd, All];
    SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
    NotebookDelete[nb];
    SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
    SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell];
    Null];
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   InputAliases -> {"eval" -> 
      RowBox[{"eval", "[", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "]"}]}];
```

Then follow this work flow:

1.-Press [ESC]eval[ESC]

2.-Write an operation, for example 2+2

3.-Press shift-enter

What actually happens is that a new input cell is written, and the old input cell is erased. I promise this is my last attempt ;)

Comment: I think in MMA 9 it is better to use `EvaluationCell` and a consequent `SelectionMove`, rather relying on `SelectionMove[nb,Previous, Cell]` to select the right cell. But I am afraid this is not exactly what the OP wants. Looks nice though :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom You are right, because in a long evaluation (one that takes several seconds) the end-user could click somewhere else in the document while the evaluation is runing, and then the NotebookWrite and NotebookDelete could destroy other cells, not those that were intended. I am also not very sure I did answer the question, however it is a nice example of NotebookWrite, SelectionMove, etc. isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I like that kind of stuff :). Glad to see you are enthousiastic too.

Comment: Ahhh, why is the bounty gone? You're solution came pretty close. The only issue that I still have is that it cannot be used to consecutively write out notation because (i) the cursor is jumping to a new cell (probably easy to change) and (ii) for example, `var` in `var + [ESC]eval[ESC]` will not lead to `var + whateverExprItyped`. I have a feeling that this can be fixed by using something else then `Cell` in `SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell]`.

Comment: @phantomas1234 yeah bounties work like that, they only stay for a week I think. Hm maybe I will take another wack at this

Comment: This doesn't work in MMA 10. The placeholder is not selected, instead the cursor is to the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do step 2 and 3 with one hotkey, by adding the item

```
Item[KeyEvent["u", Modifiers -> {Control}], 
    FrontEndExecute[
        FrontEndToken["ExpandSelection"];
        FrontEndToken["ExpandSelection"];
        FrontEnd`SelectionEvaluate[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]]
    ]
]
```

to KeyEventTranslations.tr, located at the path that is the result of

```
FileNames["KeyEventTranslations.tr", $InstallationDirectory, 
  8] // First
```