# Input alias having a place holder which gets selected when the alias is used

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting, options, input-alias

If one executes the following code

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> {"aa" -> 
 "AFunctionWithAVeryLongName[\!\(\*TagBox[FrameBox[\"input\"],\"Placeholder\"]\)]"}]
```

the front end will change <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> into a long expression with a placeholder. I want the placeholder selected after the replacement.

If I try to use `SelectionPlaceholder`, instead of `Placeholder`, then a character from `AFunctionWithAVeryLongName` gets selected.

If I try to include a tab at the end of the string,

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> {"aa" -> 
 "AFunctionWithAVeryLongName[\!\(\*TagBox[FrameBox[\"input\"],\"Placeholder\"]\:0009\)]"}]
```

the tab goes in literally as a tab character, not a tab command.

Also, I want the output to have a string, say "input", in the placeholder.

[image]

Comment: [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25693/4330). The answer there by the user matTECmatica appears to answer your question. I think that code could be slightly improved, maybe also see my comment there.

Comment: Hector, you haven't answered my question: if as I believe this is not possible from InputAliases what alternatives are acceptable to you?  What about a shortcut-key, or a palette button?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see how Mathematica would allow key modifiers for shortcuts. I am working on a palette button to be controlled by AutoHotkey.

Comment: Hector, I'm not sure what you mean.  If you doubt it is possible to create your own keyboard shortcuts please see [this search result](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=KeyEventTranslations.tr) as it surely is.  Are you going to post a new question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am looking for shortcuts available only when a package has been loaded (as opposed to system-wide ones). Also, I will post a new question because creating palette brought new challenges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> {
   "aa" -> RowBox[{"AFunctionWithAVeryLongName", "[", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "]"}]
 }
]
```

[image]

A placeholder with a name does not seem possible with Input Aliases.

Comment: Very nice! You were quick too :)

Comment: Duh!, the manual does say that InputAliases accepts "strings or box expressions."

Comment: @Hector There are lots of things the manual says that I didn't understand until someone gave me an example, or sometimes several examples.

Comment: I updated the question to make explicit the requirement on the string within the placeholder …

Comment: @Hector I'm not certain that is possible from an input alias (I'll be happy to see it if it is).  Things like [command completion templates](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29246/121) are inserted programmatically and use e.g. `SelectionMove` to select the labels.  At least that's my recollection.

Comment: @Hector would it be acceptable to make this insertion using a shortcut-key rather than an input alias?  Such things are possible with that functionality I believe.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think that would be ok. Should I open a different question?

Comment: @Hector That's up to you.  Since the text placeholder was there in the original question this isn't a case of "moving goalposts" and you don't *need* to post a new question.  On the other hand a new question may bring fresh eyes and more/better solutions.  At the moment I'm busy with another post and can't work on this.

Comment: This doesn't work in MMA 10. The placeholder is not selected, instead the cursor is to the right of it.

Comment: @Barefeg That is a known bug; see [(54595)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54595/121) and  [(55734)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55734/121).  Sadly it has been there since 10.0.0 and it still has not been corrected. :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can create a placeholder with a name if you use a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox):

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases,"aa"}] = RowBox[{
    "AFunctionWithAVeryLongName",
    "[",
    TemplateBox[{},"SelectionPlaceholder",DisplayFunction->(FrameBox["\"input\""]&)],
    "]"
}];
```

Then, using the alias "aa" produces:

[image]

which can be selected by tabbing. Alas, the placeholder is still not selected when you use the alias.