# Moving to the last placeholder with inputautoreplacements

Tags: replacement

I have had a long-standing problem when I try to use my inputautoreplacements in a text cell.  The replacements I have made include boxes that include placeholders.

When in the text cell, you type the string shortcut and then usually press the space bar.  Then your replacement is made.  Works great.  However, the cursor does not move back into any of the placeholders.  According the Wolfram via tech support this is normal behavior.

To move back in I need to press the left arrow key two times and then tab through the placeholders.  This is a pain and sometimes that doesn’t work consistently depending on the structure of the boxes.

1. I would like to find a solution that will automatically move the cursor to the closest placeholder to the left of the cursor after the auto input replacement is made.
2. If not automatic, then I would like to create a keyboard shortcut to do this instead of relying on the left arrow button which doesn’t always work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this related to the "bug" in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54595/2048)?

Comment: Yes, however according to wolfram, it is not a bug.  See my comment in that section.  As it is not a bug, I would like a solution.

Comment: Contrary to what technical support might say, [this response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151522/2048) by @ItaiSeggev, the senior kernel developer of Mathematica, confirms it is a bug.

Comment: Thank you.  I should have stayed up to date on this post.  I was assured by their developing team this wasn’t a bug but now I see that is not the case.  Good news!  Thank you.

Comment: You can navigate between placeholders using `Tab` and `Shift+Tab`.

Comment: @Kuba - that only works once you are inside the inline cell.  My issue is finding a way to get to the inline cell fast and efficiently.  Right now I have to press the left arrow twice and then tab to move into the placeholder.  I believe it can be more than this in some cases with b boxes within boxes.  So there are at least three keystrokes.  A shortcut like Control+e or some variant to move to the first placeholder would be much better for me.  According to ItaiSeggev, auto-placing the cursor into the placeholder after pressing the spacebar use to work but broke years ago.

Comment: There is no word on a fix in a while, so I am now looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: It appears this was not fixed in Version 12.  : (