# InputAliases and SelectionPlaceholder issue in V10

Tags: bugs, front-end, customization

**Bug introduced in V10.0.0 or earlier and persisting through  V12.0**

---

Let's create an example and do the test:

```
CreateDocument[{},  InputAliases -> {"[" -> 
RowBox[{"\[LeftDoubleBracket]", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[RightDoubleBracket]"}]}]
```

[image]

As you can see this is not what I expected. `SelectionPlacholder` has changed to `Placeholder`.

OS: Win7

Can you reproduce the problem? It is not only the case of custom aliases but each built-in behaves the same...

Comment: I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/dnOkw6W.png) in _v8_ Linux too.

Comment: @Öskå maybe it was only meant vor v9 ;) it still works there

Comment: I get `"\[Placeholder]"` both in v.8.0.4 and 10.0.0 under Win7 x64. But in v.8.0.4 the placeholder **is selected** while in v.10.0.0 it is not selected and when I type the text is inserted to the right of the placeholder.

Comment: I was just about to post a similar question regarding the fact that `\[SelectionPlaceholder]`s generated by input aliases are no longer selected in v10 (Mac OS X 10.9.4) but, for example, if I create an indefinite integral "template" using the typesetting palette button (equivalent to the `intt` input alias) the first placeholder is selected.

Comment: On OSX, MMA 10.3, I get a completely empty-appearing notebook, which has a cell with `InputAliases->{
 "[" -> RowBox[{
    "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", "\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
     "\[RightDoubleBracket]"}]}`

Comment: @PatrickStevens I will try to update the code later to it generates proper notebook on Mac too.

Comment: Such a simple yet important bug and directive control still couldn't give a developer enough time to fix it. :-(

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The persistence of desktop FE bugs is probably caused by focusing effort on Cloud stuff and marketing. I learned to live with this. Some bugs actually fixed in 11 but not as much as I was expecting :/

Comment: I really hoped that after the function explosion of v10 that v11 would be a stability and performance release.  I am starting to think that will never come.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard at least it seems to be the best x.0.0 for a long time.

Comment: That's good to hear.  I am still on 10.1.0.

Comment: This is the same bugs reported in [54595](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54595/).

Comment: @ItaiSeggev thanks, marked it a duplicate.