# Consistency between Enter keys

Tags: interface

[The notebook tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingANotebookInterface.html) notes that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> needs to be pressed to evaluate input; however, for the number pad, only <kbd>Enter</kbd> is required. It appears as though the use of <kbd>Shift</kbd> is inverted for the number pad and this inconsistency is rather frustrating. Looking through the settings, I haven't been able to find a solution. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Is it not Shift+Return vs. Enter? Shift+Enter evaluates and consecutively selects the next cell...  but indeed the tutorial does seem inconsistent (or I do have old key bindings).

Comment: The best thing is to use Rolf Mertig´s awesome shortcuts anyway: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85824/131

Comment: I am not understanding the problem. At least for me, it is unclear what you are asking. The fragment "...the use of Shift is inverted..." is where you lose me. Maybe it would help if you stated in precise and plain terms how your keyboard/Mathematica is behaving, and how you want it to behave

Comment: The behavior you complain about has been a feature of _Mathematica_ since V1.0. I suggest learning to live with it.