# Is there a keyboard shortcut that reproduces the code two input cells above the current cursor location?

Tags: front-end, keyboard, customization

In *Mathematica* running on OS X, <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is one of my favorite keyboard shortcuts, as it reproduces the code in the input cell above cursor location into the current cell or into a new cell when the cursor is between cells.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will reproduce the code in the input cell that is two input cells above cursor location?

Comment: I don't think so but it's possible to create one.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85823/is-it-possible-to-maintain-user-defined-shortcuts-in-a-web-installable-package and linked questions.