# Version 10.2, key shortcuts for matching brackets do not work?

Tags: bugs, linux, keyboard

**Bug introduced in 10.2**

- **System: Linux**

---

Once updated to 10.2, my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd> do not return a pair of brackets but a single right one, as if <kbd>Alt</kbd> is not pressed. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> still works.

Comment: Well, I [noticed this yesterday](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23008908#23008908)...

Comment: I cleaned your question. I have the same issue, so changes to your `KeyEventTranslations.tr` are not the issue. Additionally, I added the standard header for bugs.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know it is not just me...

Comment: Just for the record, I'm running Windows and don't have the problem.  Actually, I didn't know about that shortcut until I read this post.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chromatic Would you mind to try this on your Linux box? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89184/187

Comment: @halirutan Tried, not reproducible. Maybe you could try "Show expression" to find any clue?

Comment: I'm absolutely clueless why this happens. I noticed that everything is f*cked up after I paste something in the notebook (I first noticed it while answering a question and using OP's code). I then even specifically looked at the hex-codes of the complete clipboard to make sure nothing bad and invisible is pasted into Mathematica. I reported it to support. Let's see what they can make of it. Thanks for trying.

Comment: In linux I noticed similar problem , e.g. that things like `ctrl+shift+7` do not produce nice superscript anymore, but some very weird symbol. Do you also have that problem as well?

Comment: @NevenCaplar `ctrl + 6` for nice superscript works.

Comment: @Chromatic Thx, indeed it works :)

Comment: On Linux with German keyboard `ctrl+shift+7` should produce fractions. However, this is somehow broken in the 10.2. As a workaround I remapped fractions to `ctrl+alt+7` by adding `Item[KeyEvent["7", Modifiers -> {Control,Command}], "Fraction"]` to `KeyEventTranslations.tr`

Comment: @Chromatic Is this something you still experience beyond 10.2? I'm running v10.4 over Ubuntu 15.10 and both Alt+} and Alt+) work as expected.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I've been using the answer below since then. Good to know they fix this bug now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add this to your KeyEventTranslations.tr file it works on Linux (I only tested english keyboard layout):

```
 Item[KeyEvent["}", Modifiers -> {Command, Shift}],
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "{", After],
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "}", Before]
    }]
    ],

    Item[KeyEvent[")", Modifiers -> {Command, Shift}],
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "(", After],
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], ")", Before]
    }]
    ],
```

If so desired (and if I find time) I could add this to the [Shortcuts`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85824/29) package.

Comment: (+1) I think it would be convenient to have these in the package.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I tried shortly yesterday to update the documentation, but something did not work with my version of Workbench and Mathematica 10.2. I wished it would be easier to write documentation ...