# How to overwrite key shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard

It is very handy to have shortcuts for frequently used glyphs, e.g. `[[`, `]]`, `<|`, `|>`, and `->`. I know already that we can do this by [modifying KeyEventTranslations.tr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5215) located in

```
FileNameJoin[{
  $InstallationDirectory,
  "SystemFiles",
  "FrontEnd",
  "TextResources",
  "Macintosh"
  }]
```

Working with US keyboard layout, I added the following to the file:

```
...

Item[KeyEvent[">", Modifiers -> {Control}],
FrontEndExecute[{
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[AliasDelimiter]",After],
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"->",After],
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[AliasDelimiter]",After]
}]
],

Item[KeyEvent["[", Modifiers -> {Shift,Control}],
FrontEndExecute[{
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[AliasDelimiter]",After],
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"<|",After],
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[AliasDelimiter]",After]
}]
],

Item[KeyEvent["]", Modifiers -> {Shift,Control}],
FrontEndExecute[{
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[AliasDelimiter]",After],
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"|>",After],
FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[AliasDelimiter]",After]
}]
],

...
```

This worked splendidly for the last two or three major releases of *Mathematica*. But now in version 12, precisely what Szabolcs anticipated [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/110902) happened to me: Seemingly, new shortcuts

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>,
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, and
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

have been added, ruining my established workflow. Actually, I am not sure that these shortcuts are *new*, but starting with version 12, my former approach does work anymore. At least <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> seems to be remapped to something related to notebook cell selection. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, another shortcut that I remapped and that I use often, is already present in version 11.3 -- but the remapping worked well. So maybe the order in which the shortcuts are loaded when the FrontEnd starts has changed?

I don't use these shortcuts in the new built-in way; I'd rather prefer to overwrite them with my old settings **because I #!@&ing don't want to relearn typing every time a new version is realeased**!

I also found the [`` "Shortcuts`" `` package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85824) by Rolf Mertig, but as Rolf pointed out, it does not seem to work anymore (I have to admit that I have not tried it yet).

**Has anybody found a robust, future-proof solution for this?**

Comment: Do you have a reference for the new shortcuts that have been introduced?

Comment: I am still using version 10.1, but have you tried editing `MenuSetup.tr`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the pointer. In `MenuSetup.tr`, I was able to find the line `MenuItem["Extend Selection", "ExpandSelection", MenuKey[".", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],` but that should not modify <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or should it? Neither did I find any further remappings of ">" or "." that would fit the pattern...

Comment: @mikado Hm. Actually I haven't found them documented yet. Shift + Ctr + , is another shortcut that I use often. It worked in version 11.3 but now I find it int the menu under "Insert" -> "Table/Matrix" -> "Add Column". And it was already there in version 11.3! I gues that WRI has changed the precendences of the loading of `tr`-files...

Comment: Why aren't you storing a modified version of KeyEventTranslations.tr in the directory `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "TextResources", "Macintosh"}]` instead? I tried giving `Shift+Ctrl+.` a new short cut there, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @CarlWoll. Erm. I'd love to do that but  that directory does not exist on my hard drive. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, I think you just need to create it.

Comment: @CarlWoll Gnah. I tried that immediately when you gave me the path. Did not work either. I also tried to erase the whole `$UserBaseDirectory` and had _Mathematica_ recreate it on relaunch before creating `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "Macintosh"}]` and copying my old `KeyEventTranslations.tr` there. =/ Maybe. I should consider a fresh reinstall of Mathematica on Monday...

Comment: Did you create the file, and then quit and relaunch Mathematica? The new file only takes affect after a relaunch of Mathematica. You shouldn't have to reinstall Mathematica.

Comment: "Did you create the file, and then quit and relaunch Mathematica?" I know from experience that `KeyEventTranslations.tr` should be manipulated only with _Mathematica_ shut down (and with an external editor). And that is what I did. Several times by now. =|

Comment: Most shortcuts still work in V12, Windows, MacOS and Linux. Minimal installation is done by calling once `Import["http://www.mertig.com/s.m"]`

Comment: I tried changing my modifier, and got a shortcut to work. I had used  

Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Shift, Option}],          FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[SelectedNotebook[], "EvaluatorQuit", Automatic]]],

to force the  Kernel to quit. With version 12, when I typed the key sequence instead I saw the character Œ inserted. When I switched to use Modifiers -> {Shift, Control}, the shortcut started working.

Is there any built-in variable that describes the search path for keyboard overrides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KeyEventTranslations.tr started making problems in version 12, but just follow Mr. Wizard's advice. Some shortcuts you might like are already present in `MenuSetup.tr`, you can just add a few more in the same style.
Find the line

```
MenuItem["Matching []", "InsertMatchingBrackets", MenuKey["]", Modifiers->{"Command", "Option"}]],
```

and add few more lines before or after

```
MenuItem["Rule \[Rule]", 
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[Rule]", After]], MenuKey[">", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],
MenuItem["Double bracket \[LeftDoubleBracket]", 
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[LeftDoubleBracket]", After]], MenuKey["[", Modifiers->{"Option"}]],
MenuItem["Double bracket \[RightDoubleBracket]", 
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[RightDoubleBracket]", After]], MenuKey["]", Modifiers->{"Option"}]],
MenuItem["Left association \[LeftAssociation]", 
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[LeftAssociation]", After]], MenuKey["[", Modifiers->{"Shift", "Control"}]],
MenuItem["Right association \[RightAssociation]", 
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[RightAssociation]", After]], MenuKey["]", Modifiers->{"Shift", "Control"}]],
```

I would even add

```
MenuItem["Matching \[LeftDoubleBracket]\[RightDoubleBracket]", 
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[LeftDoubleBracket]", After],
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],"\[RightDoubleBracket]", Before],
    }], MenuKey["]", Modifiers->{"Command", "Control"}]],
```

Comment: Hah! Splendid! This works. I can even put my beloved `\[LeftArrow]` back onto Control+Shift+<. Have my accept, have my upvote! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help! If you have a lot of shortcuts to add and want to keep your Menu a bit organised, you can introduce a new grouping like this: inside `Menu["Insert", {` put `Menu["My", {` and add your shortcuts there, then close `}],`. Because every shortcut added to `MenuSetup.tr` adds an item to your menu tabs.

Comment: Ah, now it is much clearer to my how this works. Thank you once again!