# How to convert function to MenuSetup.tr form

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization, keyboard, user-interface

I have a function that removes any surrounding [] {} or () from the current selection of the notebook given by `NotebookObject[]`.

```
NotebookWrite[#, Replace[NotebookRead[#], {
     RowBox[{"(", x_, ")"}] :> x,
     RowBox[{"{", x_, "}"}] :> x,
     RowBox[{"[", x_, "]"}] :> x
     }], All] & @ NotebookObject[]
```

This works in a notebook. It would be handy to have as a keybinding. I have struggled to add it to MenuSetup.tr or KeyEventTranslations.tr. For example:

```
MenuItem["Desurround",
    FrontEndExecute[{
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], 
            Replace[FrontEnd`NotebookRead[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]], {
                RowBox[{"(", x_, ")"}] :> x,
                RowBox[{"{", x_, "}"}] :> x,
                RowBox[{"[", x_, "]"}] :> x
                }], All] }],
    MenuKey["Backspace", Modifiers->{"Control"}]
]
```

simply has no noticeable effect in the front end. I've tried several combinations of appending `` FrontEnd` ``  onto every function to no avail. FrontEndExecute gets scared of `Head`s that arn't "menu command"s such that an error is thrown for things like `FrontEndExecute[Module[...]]` or `FrontEndExecute[CombinedExpression[...]]`. I've gotten close by using `FrontEndExecute` with `FrontEndApply` to wrap my function around the selection but the logic gets complicated and messy (the strings and box forms **do not** play nice) as far as I can tell.

Is a way to have a nontrivial function like the above attached to a keybinding. Are there any examples of MenuSetup.tr files that I can use to study this sort of thing? **How can I take the above function and add its functionality to a keybinding?**

Comment: Since you are using `Replace` you need to `KernelExecute` I guess. p.s. you may want to try [DevTools\`LiveActions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184568/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Kuba for telling me about DevTools`. It is a very neat package. But I did not want to use Ctrl + ' and then Backspace. But the KernelExecute hint helped me find [16165](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16165/how-can-i-set-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-a-command?noredirect=1&lq=1) which showed how to add a command to a shortcut. The jist is, put your function/command in a .m file (no formatting, exactly how it appears in a notebook) then use this syntax in an appropriate location in the MenuSetup.tr file

```
MenuItem[
    "Desurround",
    KernelExecute @ Get["/path/to/the/file.m"],
    MenuKey["Backspace", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}],
    MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
],
```

For more information on MenuSetup.tr and KeyEvenTranslation.tr see [5212](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/automating-esc-esc-formatting/5215#5215) and [197177](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197177/how-to-overwrite-key-shortcuts) for a more up to date post on the topic. It also looks like b3m2a1's answer to [145847](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145847/how-can-i-customize-my-menus-without-reloading-menusetup-tr?rq=1) has a package that can help automate some of this stuff.

P.S. Heres an upgrade to the function that handles quotes "" as well. Here is what I ultimately put in the .m file

```
NotebookWrite[#, Replace[NotebookRead[#], {
    x_String :> StringJoin[Characters[x][[2 ;; -2]]] /; 
        First @ Characters @ x === "\"" && Last @ Characters @ x === "\"",
    RowBox[{a_String, x__, b_String}] :> 
        RowBox[{
            StringJoin[Characters[a] ~ Drop ~ 1], 
            x, 
            StringJoin[Characters[b] ~ Drop ~ -1]
        }] /; 
        StringMatchQ[a, "\"" ~~ __] && StringMatchQ[b, __ ~~ "\""],
    RowBox[{"(", x_, ")"}] :> x,
    RowBox[{"{", x_, "}"}] :> x,
    RowBox[{"[", x_, "]"}] :> x,
    RowBox[{"(", x__, ")"}] :> RowBox[{x}],
    RowBox[{"{", x__, "}"}] :> RowBox[{x}],
    RowBox[{"[", x__, "]"}] :> RowBox[{x}]
}], All] & @ SelectedNotebook[]
```