# Can one use Ctrl and cursor position to get short documentation from a function like hovering

Tags: front-end, dynamic, documentation, popup

I would like to minimize how often I use my mouse. One time where I have to use the mouse is when I hover over a function to see the options for that function and a short explanation of the usage of that function. Not the list of suggestions for auto-completion.

I would like to do the same by holding Ctrl while the cursor is next to one of the characters of the function to see the popup menu.

There is thus two questions:

- Can one use `Dynamic` to perform commands based on cursor position
- Is there a function that reproduces the output of hovering over a function or that provides similar content ?

Comment: There is a keyboard shortcut `CTRL + K` for bringing up that blue raft. You may also use `CTRL + RightArrow` before that to move cursor to the end of the symbol. More about shortcuts [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SelectingAndTypingInNotebooks.html).

Comment: @Domen thank you ! I had read the keyboard shortcuts in the past and even installed the shortcuts package by Rolf Mertig [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85824/86543) and I missed that one. That one you gave,  the `CTRL+.`  for finding precedence of functions, which I saw from a Szabolcs answer or comment by accident, and `SHIFT+UP` to extend a selected cell are now among my favorites.

Comment: @Domen actually now that I tried using it while coding I am seeing that there might have been a confusion. `CTRL + K` only brings up a list of suggestions for functions no ? I wanted to see the options and a short documentation for the function.

Comment: @Domen I found out that what I needed to do was to use `CTRL+SHIFT+K` at the end of a function. One can use `CTRL+RIGHTARROW` if the cursor is not already there.

Comment: The list of keyboard shortcuts [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) mentions that shortcut as "make template". I do not see how one can easily deduce that one could get the short documentation from there.