# How to run all cells above current one?

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, cells, keyboard, menu

In Jupyter notebook, there is a Run All Above (a certain cell) option. Is there something like Run All Above in Mathematica?

Comment: This seems to me like a dangerous way to run code. I would not do it myself. A better way is make a function of the code you want and explicitly call it.  Or to run one cell, I select it and evaluate that one cell only. But that is just me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use functions from the [Low-Level Notebook Programming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelNotebookProgramming.html) guide.

```
ClearAll[evaluateFromFirstCell];
SetAttributes[evaluateFromFirstCell, {HoldFirst}];
evaluateFromFirstCell[nb_NotebookObject : EvaluationNotebook[]] :=
 Module[{cells = Reverse@PreviousCell[EvaluationCell[], All, CellStyle -> "Input"]},
  Scan[
   SelectionMove[#, All, Cell];
    SelectionEvaluateCreateCell[nb]; &,
   cells
   ]
  ]
```

Then evaluating `evaluateFromFirstCell[]` in a notebook will evaluate all input cells that precede it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is a programmatic way to create a "Run all above", [as described in answers this question about selection of above cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16697/is-there-a-shortcut-to-select-all-cells-above-the-current-cursor-position).